# Hiding a column in a fluid bootstrap layout

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and AngularJS and I have two column fluid layout.

The two columns are declared like so -

```
<div class="chart col-md-8">...</div>
<div class="options col-md-4">...</div>
```

If the user's browser window is less than a certain width, or if they resize it to less than a certain width, I want to hide the options column and make the chart column take up the full width of the screen. How would I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look here:

[Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

If you add the `.hidden-xs` class to the options `div` it won't be visible for extra small devices (<768px). Find the appropriate class for your usage. You can use a single or a combination of the available classes for toggling content across viewport breakpoints.

```
<div class="options col-md-4 hidden-xs">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap provides specis helper classes for this. So for your situation it can be:

```
<div class="chart col-md-8 col-xs-12">...</div>
<div class="options col-md-4 hidden-xs">...</div>
```

It means that when `xs` media query is triggered `.options` column will be hidden and `.chart` will expand to full width (12 cols).

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="chart col-md-8 col-xs-12">...</div>
<div class="options col-md-4 hidden-xs">...</div>
```

Now the chart becomes full width when the sceen is less that 768px wide

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS file you can hide the chart div for a specified max-width of a screen:

```
@media ( max-width : 768px) {
    .chart {
        display:hidden;
    }
}
```

you can set the desired max-width to hide the chart in pixels.
However, you can use the standard bootstrap classes to hide anything you want for many devices.

For example:

- class="chart hidden-xs" hides it from extra small devices, like
  mobiles.
- class="chart hidden-sm" hides it from small devices, like
  tablets.
- class="chart hidden-md" hides it from medium devices, like
  13" laptops.
- class="chart hidden-lg" hides it from large devices, like normal 15.9" devices.